# Migrate from oVirt to oVirt

Tags: kvm-virtualization, migration, ovirt, rhev

We are running two independent oVirt Clusters.

**Issue:** *Moving/Migrating/Evacuating Virtual Machines from the customer cluster, over to the management cluster, to separate out management systems from the cluster runing customer systems.*

- oVirt version: 4.3.6 on all nodes in both clusters.
- ManageIQ release: Ivanchuk
- Storage: GlusterFS 2x independent systems.

The two clusters are separate and independent from one another, so they have separate Gluster volumes, separate engines. They are configured with identical network interfaces, vlans and all.

In ManageIQ, I can find the option to migrate Virtual Machines cross cluster, but I get "Missing Providers".

[image: missingproviders]

This is unexpected, as I'm expecting to see my two providers here.
Out of curiosity, I click "View VMware and Red Hat Virtualization providers", and as expected, this shows me the two RHEV providers that I'm expecting to see:

[image: providers]

Does anyone have an idea how to go through with this? It should work but the missing providers thing is really confusing to us.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Kind regards,
Stian